# Java Overload resolution - Why m(cast, cast) instead of m(match, cast)

Tags: java, overload-resolution

I'm pretty sure I can't be the first one to stumble over this but I can't find an answer. This is homework.

```
class Tier{}

class Fisch extends Tier{}

class Vogel extends Tier{}

class Huhn extends Vogel{}

class Spatz extends Vogel{}

class Karpfen extends Fisch{}

class Super{
    public void m(Tier t1, Tier t2){
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    public void m(Tier t, Fisch f){
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    public void m(Fisch f, Tier t){
        System.out.println("5");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super{
    public void m(Tier t1, Fisch t2){
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    public void m(Vogel v, Fisch f){
        System.out.println("4");
    }
}


public class TierTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tier t1 = new Tier();
        Tier t2 = new Vogel();
        Fisch f = new Karpfen();
        Vogel v1 = new Vogel();
        Vogel v2 = new Spatz();
        Huhn h = new Huhn();
        Karpfen k = new Karpfen();

        Super sup1 = new Super();
        Super sup2 = new Sub();

        sup1.m(h, v2);
        sup2.m(v1, k);   //4 expected, got 3
        sup1.m(t1, t2);
        sup1.m(v1, k);
        sup1.m(v2, f);
        sup2.m(v1, f);  //4 expected, got 3
    }
}
```

Both times a Vogel(bird) (declaration and runtime type) and some kind of fish. Why is m(Tier, Fisch) chosen over m(Vogel, Fisch) ?

The fist parameter would be a perfect match. The rest of this fits my intuition.

Sorry if I'm just too numb to find a similar question.

Have a nice weekend,
Stephan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here :

```
Vogel v1 = new Vogel();                
Karpfen k = new Karpfen();
...
Super sup2 = new Sub();
...
sup2.m(v1, k);   //4 expected, got 3
```

`sup2` is declared with the `Super` class type.
The method chosen by the compiler relies on the class of the declared variable, not on the runtime instance.
So, the compilers looks for a method that matches in the `Super` class.

In `Super` class, these are the `m()` potential method candidates :

```
public void m(Tier t1, Tier t2){
    System.out.println("1");
}

public void m(Tier t, Fisch f){
    System.out.println("2");
}

public void m(Fisch f, Tier t){
    System.out.println("5");
}
```

The compiler chooses the most specific method among other to match with `v1` and `k` arguments declared types :

This method is selected :

```
public void m(Tier t, Fisch f){
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

Now, at runtime, the method is invoked on the runtime object (polymorphism principle). 
As the runtime class that the `sup2` variable refers to is `Sub`, the overloaded method of `Sub` is invoked :

```
public void m(Tier t1, Fisch t2){
    System.out.println("3");
}
```

And for this second invocation :

```
sup2.m(v1, f);  //4 expected, got 3
```

It is exactly the same reasoning.